# ShazamKit audio recognition API pricing

Tags: android, shazam, acrcloud, shazamkit, android-audio

I am looking to add in audio recognition to my android app and implemented ACRCloud android sdk with Java. The price for ACRCloud seems to be kind of high at $6 per 1000 requests. I want to look into using the ShazamKit android sdk but cannot find any official information regarding the API price. Does anyone who used ShazamKit know how the pricing works. Would highly appreciate any help. Additionally i was wondering if there android sdk is available in java or only supports kotlin code?

I am adding a feature with auto music recognition which triggers the API every 20 seconds until stopped by the user. For this reason I am looking for the cheapest option and with ACRCloud $6 per 1000 requests may be too expensive.

Thanks